# How can i count the passengers at the subway station?

Tags: r, r-leaflet

Hello this is my first question on stackoverflow, i hope i'm doing everything right.
I want to count the passengers at the subway station.
I have four vectors with longitude and latitude of passengers and station.
I represent the stops by circles with a radius of 20 meters and the passengers with markers.
Now I want to know how many markers there are in the circles.
I've already tried to sum the markers with markerClusterOption, but the markers outside the circles are added to the markers in the circle and I just want to sum up the markers inside the circle.
My goal is to just add up the number of markers within the circles.

```
library(leaflet)
#lat and long of the Subway stations
SubwayStation_long<-c(174.764164,174.764290)
SubwayStation_lat<-c(-36.877022,-36.877844)
#lat and long of the Passengers
Passagier_long<-c(174.764,
                  174.764436,
                  174.764336,
                  174.764044,
                  174.764034,
                  174.763,
                  174.7641,
                  174.7645,
                  174.764290,
                  174.764068,
                  174.764352,
                  174.764467)
Passagier_lat<-c(-36.877,
                 -36.8770099,
                 -36.8770199,
                 -36.8770189,
                 -36.8770189,
                 -36.876,
                 -36.8779,
                 -36.8778,
                 -36.877844,
                 -36.877102,
                 -36.877814,
                 -36.877900)


tiles = getAllLeafletTiles()
tiles = tiles[c(1,3,27)]
map <- leaflet() 
for (provider in tiles) {
  map <- map %>% addProviderTiles(provider, group = provider)
}

map <- addLayersControl(
  map,
  baseGroups    = tiles,c("Station","Passengers"),
  options       = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))
map <- addMeasure(map, primaryLengthUnit = "kilometers", primaryAreaUnit = "sqmeters", activeColor = "#3D535D", completedColor = "#006400")

map<-addCircles(map,SubwayStation_long,SubwayStation_lat, group = "Station",radius = 15)

map<-addMarkers(map,Passagier_long,Passagier_lat,group = "Passengers",
                           clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(freezeAtZoom = FALSE))

map
```

[here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUgAQ.png)

[i want it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O52RM.png)

Comment: your link at the bottom is broken, appearing to be for your local desktop. Is there another way you can share the image, perhaps using SO's imgur integration?

Comment: Something like this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133625/checking-if-points-fall-within-polygon-shapefile

Comment: I added a screenshot I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

R has a package "geosphere" for calculating distances given the longitude and latitude of the two points.  This problem is the calculation of which passengers are within 20 meters of each station.

```
library(geosphere)
#create dataframe of data, first column longitude, second latitude 
subway<-data.frame(SubwayStation_long, SubwayStation_lat)
passagier<-data.frame(Passagier_long, Passagier_lat)

#proceed row by row and caluclate the distance between the station and each passenger
#return TRUE if the distance is within 20 meters
#first column of output goes with first row of station data.
within20m<-apply(subway, 1, function(x){distGeo(x, passagier)<20})

#number within 20 meters of each station
colSums(within20m)
```

Sample output from the apply statement.

```
       [,1]  [,2]
 [1,]  TRUE FALSE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE
 [3,]  TRUE FALSE
 [4,]  TRUE FALSE
 [5,]  TRUE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE  TRUE
 [8,] FALSE  TRUE
 [9,] FALSE  TRUE
[10,]  TRUE FALSE
[11,] FALSE  TRUE
[12,] FALSE  TRUE
```

This should provide acceptable performance for a reasonable number of stations and passengers. If you have a large number of stations and a large number of passengers then this solution will experience performance issues and other tools and techniques are needed.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! It‘s a good idea but i have a large number of Stations and passengers.

Comment: If that is the case, then I would suggest using a divide and conquer algorithm method into order to reduce the problem into a number of manageable problems.